# Header 'MessageKit-Swift.h' not found

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, messagekit

I'm trying to setup MessageKit within my app.  I've been researching and trying to resolve this for a week with no luck.  I'm getting an error in the module.modulemap file saying

> Header 'MessageKit-Swift.h' not found

I'm deleted dervied data, ran pod update, pod install, etc.

Here is the `module.modulemap` code

```
framework module MessageKit {
  umbrella header "MessageKit.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }
}

module MessageKit.Swift {
    header "MessageKit-Swift.h"
    requires objc
}
```

I expected MessageKit to compile within my workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I tried that pod in a test project and compiles fine without issues.

I'm using `Cocoapods 1.7.2` and `Xcode 10.2.1`, and this is my `Podfile`:

```rb
target 'MessageKitTest' do
  use_frameworks!
  pod 'MessageKit'
end
```

Tried to compile the `MessageKitTest` from the generated `xcworkspace` - all good on my end.

Try running a `pod deintegrate` then a `pod install` again.

Comment: Thanks @Matteo I've duplicated your steps and am still getting the same error.